# Proof of the Moreau Decomposition Property of Proximal Operators

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Given the prox operator i.e.

$$ \operatorname{prox}_{ h \left( \cdot \right) } \left( x \right) = \arg \min_{u} h \left( u \right) + \frac{1}{2} {\left\| u - x \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

the Moreau decomposition property says that

$$ x = \operatorname{prox}_{ h \left( \cdot \right) } \left( x \right) + \operatorname{prox}_{ {h}^{\ast} \left( \cdot \right) } \left( x \right) $$

where $h^*$ is the conjugate of $h$

I was reading a proof of this which went as follows :

1. Define $ u = \operatorname{prox}_h (x)$ and $v = x - u$
2. From optimality condition of minimization in the definition of the prox operator, $ x-u \in \partial h(u)$, so $ v \in \partial h(u)$
3. $u=x-v \in \partial h^* (v)$, hence $v = \operatorname{prox}_{h^*} (x) $

I didn't understand the 3rd step of the proof, i.e. how $ u \in \partial h^* (v)$ follows from $ v \in \partial h(u)$. Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll attempt to explain the intuition here.

There may be many affine minorants of $h$ with a given slope $y$, but we only care about the *best* one:

\begin{align}
&h(x) \geq \langle y , x \rangle - \alpha \quad \text{for all } x \\
\iff & \alpha \geq \langle y, x \rangle - h(x) \quad \text{for all } x \\
\iff & \alpha \geq \sup_x \, \langle y, x \rangle - h(x) \\
\iff & \alpha \geq h^*(y).
\end{align}

Thus, the best choice of $\alpha$ is $h^*(y)$.

(If there is no affine minorant of $h$ with slope $y$, then $h^*(y) = \infty$.)

Suppose that
\begin{equation}
v \in \partial h(u).
\end{equation}

This means: there exists some affine minorant of $h$ with slope $v$ which is exact at $u$.

Of all affine minorants of $h$ with slope $v$, the **best** one (the *closest* one) is $a(x) = \langle v, x \rangle - h^*(v)$.

Since $a$ is the best affine minorant of $h$ with slope $v$, and since *some* affine minorant with slope $v$ is exact at $u$, it follows that $a$ is exact at $u$:

\begin{equation}
h(u) = \langle v, u \rangle - h^*(v)
\end{equation}

Otherwise $a$ would not be the best.

Hence
\begin{align}
h^*(v) &= \langle u,v \rangle - h(u) \\
&= \langle u, v \rangle - h^{**}(u)
\end{align}
and we know that $\langle u, v \rangle - h^{**}(u)$ is an affine minorant of $h^*$.

Thus we have found an affine minorant of $h^*$ with slope $u$ which is exact at $v$.  This means that
\begin{equation}
u \in \partial h^*(v).
\end{equation}

In summary, note the beautiful symmetry that allowed our key step:
\begin{equation}
h(u) = \langle v, u \rangle - h^*(v) \qquad \text{ " $v$ is a subgradient of $h$ "}
\end{equation} 
becomes
\begin{equation}
h^*(v) = \langle u, v \rangle - h(u) \qquad \text{ " $u$ is a subgradient of $h^*$ "}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Read Section 22.3 of https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/teaching/math301/Lectures/Moreau-Yosida.pdf
The proof is complete in page 22-4.

Answer (score 0):

I would also include the following reference where the proof is done (which might be the one read by the author of the post): Beck's book ["First-Order Methods in Optimization", chap. 6](https://archive.siam.org/books/mo25/mo25_ch6.pdf) pages 162-163

To answer more precisely the question asked here, you should have a look at this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961520/proof-about-conjugate-and-subgradient)
of the "Conjugate Subgradient Theorem", which proves that if $h$ is proper, convex and **closed**, then
\begin{equation*}
v \in \partial h(u) \iff u \in \partial h^*(v)
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

If you pretend everything is sufficiently well-behaved, the calculus behind this is so easy that you best just do it yourself and then form whatever intuition best suits you based on it.

---

Recall
$$
(1)    \quad h^*(v):=-\min_{u} h(u)-v^Tu =: -(h(u_v) - v^Tu_v).
$$
First order optimality implies $Dh(u_v)-v^{T}=0$, or $\partial h(u) = v$ in your notation.

Differentiating (1) with respect to $v$ yields
$$
Dh^*(v)=-Dh(u_v) D_v u_v + u_v + v^TD_vu_v = (-Dh(u_v)+v^T) D_vu_v+u_v = u_v,
$$
or $\partial h^*(v) = u$, in your notation.